# How to convert months to years-and-months in java

Tags: java, date

Im new to java and I want to convert months to years. For example, If i had 18 months and divided that by 12, I would have 1.5 years but I want it as 1year and 6months.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is a math question, it has nothing to do with Java.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström Not at all irrelevant to Java. Two sophisticated frameworks have been built to handle such work, first Joda-Time and now java.time built into Java 8 and later. While this particular case could be handled by math, chances are there is much other date-time work involved as well. Using the java.time classes makes such work more self-documenting with intentions made more clear than with simple integer math. Plus the benefits of built-in support for ISO 8601 formats which ease the viewing of such data values in the debugger and logs (and data exchange too).

Comment: @BasilBourque In the specific case of converting months to years, there is always 12 months in a year, a simple division and modulo.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström Granted. For maintaining code, reading `period.getYears()` and `period.getMonths()` is much quicker to discern and surer to debug than `months / 12` and `months % 12`. Plus, if the programmer is working on this particular code, she is probably working on further date-time code. Using a date-time framework makes all that code more consistent and easier to read. But, to each his or her own.

Answer (score 21):

Use the modulus `%`.

```
int months = 18;
int years = months / 12; // 1
int remainingMonths = months % 12; // 6
```

Comment: @Giku, in that case you may want to consider improving your typing speed.

Comment: @jjj: That doesn't make sense as `double` -> `int` assignment already floors. Moreover, your line doesn't compile at all. Perhaps you made a mistake in your real code not visible in information provided so far.

Answer (score 6):

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`. The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) team also advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP]
(https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as `Interval`, `YearWeek`, `YearQuarter`, and more.

## `Period`

The [`Period`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) class tracks a span of time unrelated to the timeline in terms of years, months and days. Be sure to call [`normalized`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html#normalized--) as a habit to force it to recalculate eighteen months in terms of a year and six months.

```
Period period = Period.ofMonths( 18 ).normalized();
```

Extract the number of years and of months.

```
int years = period.getYears();
int months = period.getMonths();
```

You can call `toString` to represent this value in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format for [“durations”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations): `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`. In this format the `P` marks the beginning while `T` separates the years-months-days portion from hours-minutes-seconds portion (irrelevant in the case of this Question).

```
String output = period.toString();
```

> P1Y6M